# Sort collections by brand by percentage of profit for each brand

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server with the following columns: brand, collection, gross_profit.
There are two brands, each having several collections. I am trying to sort the collections by brand as a percentage of profit they make up for each brand. A sample desired output would look like this:

| brand | collection | gross_profit_percentage | gross_profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | OneA | 34% | 340 |
| One | OneB | 33% | 330 |
| One | OneC | 33% | 330 |
| Two | TwoA | 50% | 500 |
| Two | TwoB | 40% | 400 |
| Two | TwoC | 10% | 100 |

I have tried the following, which is obviously wrong because SQL does not recognize columns that I have previously created within the same query.

```
SELECT 
    brand,
    collection,
    gross_profit,
    SUM(gross_profit) OVER (PARTITION BY brand, collection) AS collection_gross_profit_total,
    SUM(gross_profit) OVER (PARTITION BY brand) AS brand_gross_profit_total,
    ((collection_gross_profit_total / brand_gross_profit_total) * 100) AS gross_profit_percentage
FROM dbo.Data$    
WHERE Year='2018'
GROUP BY brand, collection, gross_profit;
```

Error Messages:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 94
> Invalid column name 'collection_gross_profit_total'.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 94
> Invalid column name 'brand_gross_profit_total'.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the error, you can't use aliases like `collection_gross_profit_total` at the same level they're defined. You'd need to wrap it in a derived query or CTE, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71588575/8895292).

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
select t.brand,
       t.collection,
       t.gross_profit,
       t.collection_gross_profit_total, t.brand_gross_profit_total,
       ((t.collection_gross_profit_total / convert(decimal(16,2), t.brand_gross_profit_total)) * 100) AS gross_profit_percentage
from   ( SELECT brand,
                collection,
                gross_profit,
                SUM(gross_profit) OVER (PARTITION BY brand, collection) AS collection_gross_profit_total,
                SUM(gross_profit) OVER (PARTITION BY brand) AS brand_gross_profit_total
         FROM dbo.Data    
         --WHERE Year='2018'
         GROUP BY brand, collection, gross_profit
       ) t
```

The [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c4b6194493d736d6a3b0b43e93f8b88) contains also another option to do it